# "No Selections are Available" error when accessing content container

Tags: integration, sonos

I'm having problem with backend integration with Sonos.

1. API has been implemented according to WSDL provided by Sonos
2. API returns a data for container X
3. All tests pass in Sonos's self-testing tool

But when I'm trying to submit the integration to Sonos for review, I'm getting a submission rejection from Sonos with the next reason:

- "No Selections are Available" when accessing content in X container.

Problem is that the official documentation (and rejection message) has no any details on such error message.

What that means?

**EDIT**:

getMetadata request (from smapiConfig-DEBUG.log of self-testing tool):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <tns:credentials>
         <tns:deviceId>00-00-00-00-00-00:Z</tns:deviceId>
         <tns:deviceProvider>Sonos</tns:deviceProvider>
         <tns:sessionId>123</tns:sessionId>
      </tns:credentials>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadata>
         <ns1:id>FEATURED_RELEASES</ns1:id>
         <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
         <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
      </ns1:getMetadata>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

getMetadata response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getMetadataResponse>
         <ns1:getMetadataResult>
            <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
            <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
            <ns1:total>100</ns1:total>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>ALBUM:104567018</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>album</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>Communion</ns1:title>
               <ns1:artist>Years &amp; Years</ns1:artist>
               <ns1:artistId>ARTIST:101412542</ns1:artistId>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>https://example.com/0004567018_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
            <ns1:mediaCollection>
               <ns1:id>ALBUM:104567238</ns1:id>
               <ns1:itemType>album</ns1:itemType>
               <ns1:title>The Way Back Up</ns1:title>
               <ns1:artist>Prides</ns1:artist>
               <ns1:artistId>ARTIST:102159674</ns1:artistId>
               <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>
               <ns1:canEnumerate>true</ns1:canEnumerate>
               <ns1:canCache>true</ns1:canCache>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>https://example.com/0004567238_200.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
            </ns1:mediaCollection>
            <!-- ... other 98 mediaCollections ... -->
          </ns1:getMetadataResult>
      </ns1:getMetadataResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Generally that error would imply that no content was returned by the SOAP request.  It is valid for containers to be empty so it is possible there are just no results (mediaCollections or mediaMetadata) being returned by that particular getMetadata request. 

Can you share the getMetadata XML response that is leading to this result?

Comment: @SonosDeveloperAdvocacy Check the edit please

Comment: Can you try adding your service to your system using CustomSd (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/134)? Once you have done that, launch your service on the Sonos Controller (it is easier to do wireshark traces and troubleshoot if you use one of the desktop controllers), select Featured Releases and then select an item from within that container. Our testers were getting no results found when selecting an album from within Feature Releases when using a controller.